# Why wont storybook run in my react project after install?

Tags: reactjs, npm, storybook

I have been trying to build my first project using react and storybook.

I can run react fine, and I can install storybook, but when I try npm run storybook I get the below error and it wont run.

I have read the storybook documentation multiple times - https://storybook.js.org/

I have also read 2 great articles detailing the steps of how to start your own project using react and storybook - https://auth0.com/blog/setting-up-a-component-library-with-react-and-storybook/ and https://auth0.com/blog/building-a-component-library-with-react-and-storybook/

However despite taking great care in following this step by step, I keep getting the below error.

I am using windows 10, I dont know if that possibly is causing some issue? Any help on getting this to run would be greatly appreciated.

```
$ npm run storybook

> react-portfolio@0.1.0 storybook C:\Users\gemma\desktop\react-portfolio
> start-storybook -p 9001 -c .storybook

C:\Users\gemma\Desktop\react-portfolio\node_modules\@storybook\core\dist\server\config\webpack.config.default.js:13
return { ...storybookBaseConfig,
^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gemma\Desktop\react-portfolio\node_modules\@storybook\core\server.js:1:92)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-portfolio@0.1.0 storybook: `start-storybook -p 9001 -c .storybook`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-portfolio@0.1.0 storybook script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: You will need to migrate to latest nodejs version. Looks like you are using older version of nodejs. https://tecadmin.net/upgrade-nodejs-via-npm/ this should help.

Comment: You can check version compatibility https://node.green/#ES2018 for support for "object spread properties"

Comment: Thank you @SaurabhNemade you were right! I thought I had the latest version already but I didnt and now I updated it and it works!

Comment: Welcome. Glad to help out :)